# How to set different php version for phpadmin

Tags: linux, apache, phpmyadmin, centos7

I have setup LAMP stack on centos 7 and installed two php versions php 5.6 and php 8.1. Also install php-fpm for both versions and running fine. By default my phpmyadmin is using version php 5.6 but I want to change php version of phpmyadmin to 8.1. But don't want to remove or change php 5.6 due to requirement of my site.

I have used this in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` :

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9074"
</FilesMatch>
```

But it does not work.

**Note**: I used this `"proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9074"` because php-fpm of php v8.1 is running on port 9074.

Can someone help out on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the config in phpmyadmin file and if the versions are already loaded side-by-side you'll just have to add this in apache conf:

```
 <Location /path/to/phpmyadim> 
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/path/to/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
 </Location>
```

Comment: I have checked and searched but did not found php8.1-fpm.sock on my machine. However,  i have checked status of php81-php-fpm.service and its up and running. Can you please help out?

Comment: Here is update: I have added your provided script in '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf' file then restarted apache but phpmyadmin is still using php v5.6